# High TIME_WAIT during concurrent access to Neo4j REST server

Tags: tcp, io, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, neo4j

I'm running a Neo4j instance and accessing it from my Ruby on Rails application over REST. Recently, I have observed that during moderate traffic surges, concurrent requests to my Neo4j REST server end up with **too many connections in TIME_WAIT state (as high as ~14000)**. This, eventually, is resulting in a heavy latency on my web application.

I'm running this Neo4j instance containing about 10M edges and 2M vertices on a c1.medium (1.7GiB, 2 CPU cores) EC2 instance. Neo4j wrapper configuration is given **-Xmx as 1024M** (1 GiB). My current ulimit is set to 100000.

`$ ulimit -n
100000`

I have referred http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/linux-performance-guide.html (I'm on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS). Doing a

`$watch grep -A 1 dirty /proc/vmstat`

Gives me intermittent values of 100-150 in nr_dirty. Sample output:

```
Every 2.0s: grep -A 1 dirty /proc/vmstat                                                                                                                     Sat Nov  3 13:25:53 2012
nr_dirty 148
nr_writeback 0
--
nr_dirty_threshold 83748
nr_dirty_background_threshold 41874
pgpgin 131920234
```

I can see consistent Block IO (store is on EBS) and a very number of high context switches and interrupts.

```
$ vmstat 1 100
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- -system-- ----cpu----
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa
 0  0 141544  32244   3548 319952    1    1    67    36   16   11 11  1 87  1
 3  0 141544  31640   3556 320036    0    0   124   100 3649 4269 48  4 47  1
 0  0 141544  30648   3564 320116    0    0    76   168 2048 2660 24  3 71  3
 1  0 141544  29780   3580 320124    0    0     0   196 4285 6064 31  6 62  2
 0  0 141544  29780   3588 320116    0    0     0    80  826 2264  6  0 92  2
 0  0 141544  29408   3588 320304    0    0   176    52  952 1873 11  1 86  1
 0  0 141544  29408   3596 320296    0    0     0    40  161  389  0  0 99  0
 0  0 141544  29408   3596 320296    0    0     0     0   47   79  0  0 100  0
 0  1 141544  21720   3596 327992    0    0  7660     0  412  359  5  0 87  8
 0  0 141544  21720   3604 327956    0    0     0    80  224  652  0  1 99  1
 0  0 141544  21720   3604 327968    0    0     0    24  131  359  0  0 99  1
 0  0 141544  21720   3604 327968    0    0     0    24  132  359  0  0 100  0
 0  0 141544  21720   3612 327960    0    0     0    56  141  360  0  0 98  1
 0  0 141544  21100   3612 328580    0    0   608     0   99  173  2  0 97  1
 0  0 141544  20604   3620 328700    0    0   120   172 1172 2381 19  2 77  2
 0  0 141544  20604   3620 328700    0    0     0     0   49   85  0  0 100  0
 0  0 141544  20604   3620 328704    0    0     0    32  172  415  1  0 99  0
 1  0 141544  20480   3628 328696    0    0     0   108  578  755 41  1 56  3
 2  0 141544  20356   3628 328708    0    0     0     0  276   49 50  0 50  0
 1  0 141544  20480   3628 328708    0    0     0     0  287   49 50  0 50  0
 4  0 141560  20960   3648 328076   32   20  1092   356 4959 5501 68  6 23  3
 1  0 141560  20340   3656 328224    0    0   276    88 1181 1208 69  2 25  4
 1  0 141560  20340   3656 328280    0    0     0    16  290   53 50  0 50  0
 1  0 141560  20340   3656 328280    0    0     0     0  277   52 50  0 50  0
 1  0 141560  18868   3696 329116    0    0   844   376 2818 2112 67  2 26  5
 1  0 141560  18868   3696 329132    0    0     0     0  287   56 50  0 50  0
 1  0 141560  18868   3696 329132    0    0     0     0  280   46 50  0 50  0
```

I don't think nr_dirty values are too high. I'd be glad if someone could confirm if setting

```
vm.dirty_background_ratio = 50
vm.dirty_ratio = 80
```

as illustrated in http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/linux-performance-guide.html would help here?

Or is it that **I have exhausted the available memory (free memory is ~14M which is too low) -> Block IO -> high TIME_WAIT**? In that case, would just moving this instance to an m1.large (7.5 GiB, 2 CPU cores) help?

Is there something else which I'm missing here?

Comment: Do you mean the ***TIME_WAIT*** state?

Comment: Yes, corrected it to TIME_WAIT now. Thanks for pointing out! :)

Comment: So, the TCP connections are not getting closed?

Comment: Doesn't look like the connections are getting closed. I had changed the value of /proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout from 60 to 20 a few hours back. Haven't tested it against a traffic surge so far. I think I should be able to get the results in another 5 hours or so.

Comment: TIME_WAIT means they *are* getting closed. The state only lasts two minutes, and it shouldn't cause high latency. What's the *actual* problem here?

Comment: @EJP I have been checking server stats for the last week and TIME_WAIT counts have stayed consistent. If this means too many connections being opened (and closed eventually), then does it mean I'm looking in the wrong direction? Could the number of Block IO, context switches and interrupts be a problem here?

Comment: Lots of TIME_WAITs can be a problem if it causes you to get bind() failure when creating outbound sockets. It doesn't cause latency. If you have a latency problem, look elsewhere.